# ngChange is called when model changed programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a problem when angular's ng-change is called when model is changed programmatically.

```
$scope.sendMessage = function() {
    $scope.message = "Message sent";
}

$scope.confirmed = true;
$scope.mySelectBox = $scope.selects[1];

<select ng-model="mySelectBox"
        ng-options="item.name for item in selects track by item.name"
        ng-change="sendMessage()">
</select>
```

Here is code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/R4MO86ihMrauHXhpCMxi?p=preview

Message should be null, because `sendMessage` shouldn't be called. Model is changed programmatically.

Comment: Hm, it might be something weird with the way the `ng-select` is intializing.  The `ng-change` works as expected and does not fire when the dropdown value is changed programmatically after intialization.  I've made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twn347d3/) based on your demo.

Comment: Yes, very strange. Probably could be reported as an issue?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same kind of issue in another context when changing programmatically the model with values collected through an HTTP request (see link below). Did you find a solution or did you declare the bug to the Angular JS team in GitHub ? TIA. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464323/setting-scope-mymodel-element-with-ng-change-enters-in-infinite-loop).

Comment: We  removed track by and added additional property to options during init phase.

Comment: This issue happends only when you set NULL to your ng-model, kTT's answer solved this issue nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs, you're right.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

but this seems to be a bug caused by the order in which the events are hooked up

The best way round it - with resorting to js handler (onchange)

```
$scope.$watch("mySelectBox", function(a,b) {
    if (a.name!=b.name) {
       $scope.message = "Message sent! (old="+b.name+', new='+a.name+')';
    }
  });
```

See plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZbxS1tszppR9SrNqxVB?p=preview

HTH

Answer (score 17):

You can try with [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). See this plunker for reference http://plnkr.co/edit/BdKx62RW5Ls2Iz1H3VR1?p=preview.

In my example I used `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change', debounce: { change: 0 } }"` and it seems to work. It only runs function provided in ngChange when I change the selection. On initialize phase `message` stays empty.

Comment: This sould be marked as correct answer because you are not forced to modify function that is called by ng-change. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The ng-change callback is changed on each model change, and it treats the initial setup as such change. What you might want to do is to run desired code **only after user interacts with it**. You can check the **$touched** property of the field:

```
<form name="exampleForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="mySelectBox" name="mySelectBox"
          ng-options="item.name for item in selects track by item.name"
          ng-change="sendMessage()">
  </select>
  <p>message = {{message}}</p>
</form>


$scope.sendMessage = function() {
    if ($scope.exampleForm.mySelectBox.$touched) {
        $scope.message = "Message sent";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing value to model in controller ,so whenever you will set value of model which is matching with list it will call ng-change:

See updated plunker:    
http://plnkr.co/edit/f3xGmKesLFbzti56WLyH?p=preview

Comment: That's not an answer for that question.